# How to position element next to relative element

Tags: css, css-position, css-float

i have navbar looking like this on the markups
[image]

i want my Sales text to be aligned with the other menu items, while icon can be different size

[image]

any tips how to achieve desired result? i've tried to play with position and float property but had no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `max-width` and `max-height` to a div container that surrounds your icon. Something like this:

```js
<h6>
  <div style="height: 64px; width: 64px; max-height: 64px; max-width: 64px">
    <FontAwesomeIcon className="{styles.icon}" icon="{icon}" />
  </div>
  <span className="{styles.text}">{text}</span>
</h6>
```